# Can't proceed to next routes because my ajax keep return 422 status

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting up a progress-bar on my page which will triggered by clicking submit button. As what i learnt in some tutorial, it require Ajax to make it run, and keep return error 422 when the uploads done, and preventing me to go to POST routes. Is something wrong in my code? Or if there's any other solutions for making progress-bar?

I've tried to checking my code, looked on my Ajax settings and it seems everything just right. But the Ajax response still code 422.

```
@php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
@endphp

@extends('template.master')
@section('title', 'Upload Data')
@section('head')
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
@endsection
@section('content')
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Upload Your File</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <br />
    <form method="POST" action="/uploadpage/submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
        <div class="col-8">
            <input type="file" id="file-upload" name="file-box" class="form-control-file" />
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="temporary-checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
                    </div>
                    &nbsp; Temporary
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col-6">
        <input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <br />
    <div class="progress">
            <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                    0%
            </div>
    </div>


    <br />

    <div class="alert alert-primary">
        <strong>Temporary file</strong> will be available for 5 days.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" id="danger-upload" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        The maximum size of file to upload is <strong>1Gib</strong>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("#file-upload").change(function(){
            if(this.files[0].size > 1000000000){
                jQuery("#file-upload").val("");
            }else{
                $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', "0").css('width', "0" + '%').text("0" + '%');
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();

                var formData = new FormData($('form#file-input')[0]);

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    xhr : function() {
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {

                            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                                $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%').text(percent + '%');
                            }

                        });

                        return xhr;
                    },
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/uploadpage/submit',
                    data : formData,
                    processData : false,
                    success : function() {
                        alert('File uploaded!');
                    },
                    error : function(lala){
                        alert('File is Stuck \nError Code: ' + lala.status + ' ' + lala.statusText);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

and my routes:

```php
Route::post('/uploadpage/submit', 'FileController@submit');
```

EDIT:
And here is my File Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\File;
use DateTime;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    private $file, $submitted_file;
    private $upload_link = "storage";

    private function generateId($temporary){
        $generated_string = ''; 
        if($temporary == true)
            $generated_string = '10';
        else $generated_string = '90';

        $generated_string = $generated_string.time();

        return $generated_string;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->file = $_SESSION["files"];
        $this->submitted_file = $_SESSION["filetoup"];

        $this->file->save();
        $this->move($this->upload_link, $this->file->name);


    }

    public function submit(Request $request){
        $this->file = new File();

        $this->validate($request, [
            'file-box' => 'required',
            'temporary-checkbox' => 'nullable'
        ]);

        $this->submitted_file = $request->file('file-box');

        $this->file->name = $this->submitted_file->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->file->type = $this->submitted_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->file->size = $this->submitted_file->getSize();
        $this->file->temporary = $request->input('temporary-checkbox');
        $this->file->id = $this->generateId($request->input('temporary-checkbox'));
        $_SESSION["files"] = $this->file;
        $_SESSION["filetoup"] = $this->submitted_file;

        return view('confirmpage')->with('files', $this->file);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I'm expect that i will directed to my next route `/uploadpage/submit`.

Comment: A 422 error means that validation is failing.

Comment: @Rwd Thank you for your clue. But can i get a clear explanation about what kind of validation is this?

Comment: Hello! Can you show me your FileController controller code?

Comment: Without seeing your validation logic/controller code I wouldn't be able to say...even then I probably still couldn't say for sure what the actual errors are. `console.log(lala)` inside the `error()` method, this should contain the error object with the messages in it.

Comment: @МаксимАбдалов Here i edit my question by adding File Controller

Comment: @Rwd I Will try

Comment: Just an FYI, don't use PHP's super globals with Laravel. You should instead access them via the `Request` class e.g. https://laravel.com/docs/master/session#using-the-session